# How do I get children component's node / ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have my App.js where I render all the components used to build the UI like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header id='header' title="Nice title"/>
        <WelcomeScreen id='welcomeScreen'/>
        <Menu id='meniu'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to implement a scroll spy but I need to access the nav nodes from the Header component into the App.js. I tried setting a ref to the specific node in the Header like this:

```
<NavItem ref={(ref) => { this.homeScreen = ref; }}>
    <NavLink href='#welcomeScreen'>Despre noi</NavLink>
</NavItem>
<NavItem ref={(ref) => { this.menuScreen = ref; }}>
    <NavLink href='#meniu'>Meniu</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

But I don't know how do I use that ref in order to put them in the scroll spy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a unique ref

```
<NavItem ref="homeScreen"><Component /><NavItem />
```

no need for a function

Comment: I did that using callback ref (if I spelled it right)

Comment: try like this in the Component constructor but I'm guessing`constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myRef = null;

    this.setRef = element => {
      this.myRef = element;
    };`

Comment: I think that you're passing the ref of the Component not a NavItem

Comment: The thing is the Header component is in an external file and it's being imported in the App.js, but I can't make the ref accessible from the parent component :\

Comment: probably u need to refer to this.refs.perent.refs.children https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/202#issuecomment-52765041

Comment: String refs are deprecated.

Comment: I'll try and do something and come with a result